# Как запретить выполнение определенных команд в CMD Windows 10?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

Нужно чтобы система не давала выполнить определенную команду в командной строке. Полное отключение CMD не подходит.
Пример команды -   cd C:\%date:~0,5%   (папка)

Comment: Какую именно команду? Мы же не можем читать ваши мысли.

Comment: Пример команды -   cd C:\%date:~0,5%   (папка)